# Convert an html table into json objects in python

Tags: python, html, json, dictionary, python-2.x

Im trying to convert an html table into json objects and writing it into a file. Basically it is a printer data fetched from the printer setup page.

this is my code,

```
html_data = urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.2.198/sys_count.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data,"lxml")

table_data = [[cell.text for cell in row("td")]
                         for row in soup.body.find_all('table', attrs={'class' : 'matrix'})]



with open('/home/abc/Desktop/JsonData.txt', 'w') as outfile:
   json.dump(table_data, outfile, sort_keys = 'true', indent = 4, separators=(',',':'),
 ensure_ascii=False)
```

Output is :

```
[
    [
        "Black & White",
        "79555",
        "Full Colour",
        "0"
    ],
    [
        "Copy",
        "30697",
        "Printer",
        "48798",
        "Others",
        "60",
        "Scan Send",
        "Black & White",
        "648",
        "Full Colour",
        "747"
    ],
    [
        "Document Feeder",
        "11709",
        "Duplex",
        "13799"
    ]
]
```

I want the output to be -

```
{
    {
        "Black & White":        "79555",
        "Full Colour":        "0"
    },
```

and so on for other tables....

tried a lot of ways but stuck on type errors when I try converting a list to dict. Need help.

FYI, I am using python 2.7. If that helps.

Adding a picture of the Printer page for more details.

[Snapshot of printer setup page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyhWV.png)

Comment: edit question and use button `{}` to format code and outputs - to make them more readable.

Comment: If you just had lists of (key, value) pairs it'd be easy to convert that list of lists into a list of dicts. But you have `"Scan Send"` in there that looks like a key without a matching value. Or maybe it's an additional value for the "Others" key. Or maybe it's a key for a sub-dict containing the ["Black & White", "648", "Full Colour", "747" ] stuff. This makes the task a bit trickier.

Comment: Ok. So "Scan Send" _should_ be a key for a subdict. But it's not easy to see that from the `table_data` list because the way you've extracted the table data loses that structural information. We _could_ just hard-code that into the program. Are there likely to be any other keys that, like "Scan Send", are followed by data that needs go into a sub-dict?

Comment: why don't you just store the data in the dict

Comment: You desired output is not JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
table_data = [
    [
        "Black & White",
        "79555",
        "Full Colour",
        "0"
    ],
    [
        "Copy",
        "30697",
        "Printer",
        "48798",
        "Others",
        "60",
        "Scan Send",
        "Black & White",
        "648",
        "Full Colour",
        "747"
    ],
    [
        "Document Feeder",
        "11709",
        "Duplex",
        "13799"
    ]
]
final_data = []
for data in table_data:
    d = dict([(k, v) for k,v in zip (data[::2], data[1::2])])
    final_data.append(d)


print (final_data)
[{'Black & White': '79555', 'Full Colour': '0'}, {'Others': '60', 'Printer': '48798', '648': 'Full Colour', 'Scan Send': 'Black & White', 'Copy': '30697'}, {'Document Feeder': '11709', 'Duplex': '13799'}]
```

Comment: Thanks harsha. Tried your code. Works great except the Full Colour key values are inverted. So the output is something like this [
    {
        "Black & White":"79556",
        "Full Colour":"0"
    },
    {
        "648":"Full Colour",
        "Copy":"30697",
        "Others":"60",
        "Printer":"48799",
        "Scan Send":"Black & White"
    },
    {
        "Document Feeder":"11709",
        "Duplex":"13799"
    }
]

Comment: @Matin as always problem is `Scan Send` which in oryginal HTML has two subelements. So real problem is during scraping.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is better version without `range(len())`.

```
table_data = [
    [
        "Black & White",
        "79555",
        "Full Colour",
        "0"
    ],
    [
        "Copy",
        "30697",
        "Printer",
        "48798",
        "Others",
        "60",
        "Scan Send",
        "Black & White",
        "648",
        "Full Colour",
        "747"
    ],
    [
        "Document Feeder",
        "11709",
        "Duplex",
        "13799"
    ]
]

result = []

for row in table_data:
    d = dict()
    for i in range(0, len(row)-1, 2):
        d[row[i]] = row[i+1]
    result.append(d)
```

Result:

```
[ 
  {
    'Black & White': '79555', 
    'Full Colour': '0'
  },
  {
    '648': 'Full Colour',
    'Copy': '30697',
    'Others': '60',
    'Printer': '48798',
    'Scan Send': 'Black & White'
  },
  {
    'Document Feeder': '11709', 
    'Duplex': '13799'
  }
]
```

But seems some data can be incorrect so it now gives `'648': 'Full Colour'` which looks strange. Maybe you have to first remove `"Scan Send"` from data.

Comment: See my comment on the question re `"Scan Send"`.

Comment: I am trying to fetch this data directly from the printer setup page and I am trying to make this code generic so that I can get the values of different printers just by changing the ip address. I just added a snapshot of the printer setup page for reference.

Comment: @PM2Ring I saw this problem when I saw my results. It can be problem because not always it have to be text `'Scan Send'`

Comment: @Matin now I see screenshot and problem is how you scrape data. You have to check if you have 3 elements in row and get from first column `ROWSPAN` - so scraping code will be more complex.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, this task is tricky because the way you've extracted the table data loses important structural information from the original HTML table.

But anyway... here's a solution that deals with `"Scan Send"`. If there are other keys like `"Scan Send"` that introduce a sub-dict you can add them to the `special_keys` set.

The `list_to_dict` recursively creates a dictionary from the `row` list. First, it creates an iterator object from `row`. We get the next item from that iterator & assume it's a key. If it's a special key we recurse on the remainder of the row, using the returned dict as the value for that key. Otherwise, we just get the next string from the iterator and use that as the value for the current key.

```
import json

table_data = [
    ["Black & White", "79555", "Full Colour", "0"],
    ["Copy", "30697", "Printer", "48798", "Others", "60", 
        "Scan Send", "Black & White", "648", "Full Colour", "747"],
    ["Document Feeder", "11709", "Duplex", "13799"]
]

special_keys = {"Scan Send"}

def list_to_dict(row):
    d = {}
    it = iter(row)
    for s in it:
        if s in special_keys:
            v = list_to_dict(it)
        else:
            v = next(it)
        d[s] = v
    return d

table_dicts = [list_to_dict(row) for row in table_data]
print(json.dumps(table_dicts, sort_keys=True, indent = 4))
```

**output**

```
[
    {
        "Black & White": "79555",
        "Full Colour": "0"
    },
    {
        "Copy": "30697",
        "Others": "60",
        "Printer": "48798",
        "Scan Send": {
            "Black & White": "648",
            "Full Colour": "747"
        }
    },
    {
        "Document Feeder": "11709",
        "Duplex": "13799"
    }
]
```

This strategy will *only* work if we can guarantee that all the items following a special key in a given row are supposed to go into the sub-dict of that special key. If that's not the case, then we need a different strategy...

---

FWIW, here's a dict comprehension version of `list_to_dict`:

```
def list_to_dict(row):
    it = iter(row)
    return {s: list_to_dict(it) if s in special_keys else next(it) for s in it}
```